# Нужна помощь в позиционировании и z-index (CSS)

Tags: css

Ставлю для div position: relative, z-index: 2, а для 2х его псевдоэлементов position:absolute и z-index: 1, вопрос: почему псевдоэлементы накладываются поверх моего основного div-а?
P.S. div имеет размер и background-image

```
    <div class="people__img people__img--3"></div> 
&__img {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    margin: 76px 0 70px;
    height: 108px;
    width: 108px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    &--1 {
      background: center / cover no-repeat url(../images/testimonials/testimonial-ava-1.jpg);
    }
::before {
      content: "";
      z-index: 1;
      position: absolute;
      height: 44px;
      width: 108px;
      background-color: $buttonBgrCo;
      border-radius: 12px;
      transform: rotate(-60deg);
      right: 45%;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приведите код, чтобы Вам могли помочь.

Answer (score 0):

У вашего `div` появляется свой [контекст наложения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context) из-за свойства `position: relative`. То есть он образует собственную локальную систему координат для `z-index` дочерних элементов.

Чтобы этого не было, сделайте картинку отдельным элементом со своим `z-index: 2` внутри элемента `&__img`.